# получение и вывод объекта JSON

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Здравствуйте! Есть страница, которая выводит сообщения из бд в таблицу, которые подгружаются с помощью ajax(json):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var idFrom = 1;
        var idTo = 67;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'showMessage', 'idFrom': idFrom, 'idTo': idTo},
            success: function (data) {
               data = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var id in data){
                $("tr[class= 'tr'").append($("<td class = 'userName'"> + id + "</td>"));
                $("tr[class= 'tr'").append($("<td class = 'textMessage'"> + data[id] +  "</td>"));
               }
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<div class="all">
 ...
 </div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Отправитель:</th>
        <th>Текст:</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="myTr">
        <td class="userName"></td>
        <td class="textMessage"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

И страница, которая это все обрабатывает:

```
  <?
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "project");

  $idFrom = $_POST['idFrom'];
  $idTo = $_POST['idTo'];


  $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT fromMessage,message FROM `messages` WHERE 
  (fromMessage, toMessage) IN (('$idFrom', '$idTo'), ('$idTo', '$idFrom')) ORDER BY id DESC");


 while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
   $fromMessage = ($row['fromMessage']);
   $userName = getUserName($fromMessage, $mysqli);
   echo json_encode(array($userName => $row['message']));
 }

 function getUserName($fromMessage, $mysqli){
   $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT users.name FROM `messages` INNER JOIN `users` ON 
 messages.fromMessage=users.idUser WHERE messages.fromMessage='$fromMessage'");

 while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userName = $row['name'];
 }
 return $userName;
 }
```

В результате получаю JSON: `{"user1":"testeste"}{"user1":"test2"}{"user2":"test"}`. Но никак не могу вывести в таблицу. Должно быть так; Отправитель: user1, Текст: testeste и т.д. PS Заранее прошу прощения за не совсем понятный код.